# Access Email Address from DetailView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to access the email address in the `DetailsView` but getting this error:

```
Null Reference Exception was unhandled by user code
```

This is what I have in my code:

```
TextBox EmailAddress = this.DetailsView1.FindControl("Email") as TextBox;
string myemail = EmailAddress.Text;
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
mailMessage.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fromEmailAddress"]);
mailMessage.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("myemail")); //ERROR
```

So, the code is stopping at this line and getting the error I mentioned:

```
mailMessage.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("myemail"));
```

Comment: before i try to do any of this myself, when the application crashes, it should bring up the debugger.  At the bottom of your debugger screen should be a tab named "locals"  that tells you what your local variables are.  there is also a tab called "watch" you can click on that tab and then type something like `this.DetailsView1.FindControl("Email")` and see if it's retrieving the text box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't help but notice that "myemail" in your code is in quotes:

```
mailMessage.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("myemail"));
```

try changing it to the following maybe?

```
mailMessage.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(myemail));
```

referencing

```
string myemail = EmailAddress.Text;
```

Also, use the debugger

Comment: i have changed but still no luck

Answer (score 1):

I notice that you assign an email address to the `mailMessage.From` property but use the `Add` method on the `mailMessage.To` property without assigning anything to `To` beforehand.

I suspect, just from the code you posted and the message you're getting, that you have to assign something to `To` first.